# Web API is working for Blazor Server/Postman/Swaggar but not working for .net MAUI APPLICATION for both Windows and Android can anyone help me?

Tags: .net, maui, webapi

Web API is working for Blazor Server/Postman/Swaggar but not working for .net MAUI APPLICATION for both Windows and Android can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Your question does not include any detail that we could use to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.